# Create a macro to copy web text and save it to a file

Tags: python, pyautogui

My code is here

```
import pyautogui
import keyboard
import time
import sys

def find_xy():  #find my position of mouse
    while 1:
        position = pyautogui.position()
        if keyboard.is_pressed('enter'):
            print(position)
            time.sleep(0.2)
        elif keyboard.is_pressed(';'):
            sys.exit()
    return 0
#Start => enter, End = ;


def doubleclick(): 
    while 1:
        pyautogui.doubleClick(x=228,y=631)
        time.sleep(2)
        if keyboard.is_pressed(';'):
                sys.exit()
    return 0

def copynpaste(): 
    while 1:
        pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')
        time.sleep(0.1)
        pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')
        time.sleep(2)
        pasteAtFile()
        if keyboard.is_pressed(';'):
                sys.exit()

def pasteAtFile():
    result = clipboard.paste()
    data = str(clipboard.paste())+"\n"
    f = open('test.text', 'a')
    f.write(data)
    f.close

def main():
    time.sleep(10)
    doubleclick()
    copynpaste()
    if keyboard.is_pressed(';'):
                sys.exit()
    
main()
```

It runs normally until double-clicked, but copying and pasting into a file does not work. TT

and Exit(';') doesn't work, what should I do?

I was trying to copy a specific piece of text from the web (which changed continuously) at certain intervals and paste it into a file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.